# How to get the cluster time in MongoDB using the C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

So `IClientSessionHandle.ClusterTime` returns null for me:

```
using (var session = await client.StartSessionAsync())
{
   var time = session.ClusterTime; // null
}
```

I would be more than happy to get the result of `Date()` from the server, but it completely eludes me how something so simple can be done. I'm not interested in whether this is a good idea or not, I just want to know what the server thinks the current time is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this value is not what you need. It returns the last seen `clusterTime` when an operation was executed. See this [doc](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/sessions/driver-sessions.rst#clustertime). You may see more detailed $clusterTime description [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/#std-label-command-response)

Look at `db.runCommand({ isMaster: 1 })` response and in particular at `$localTime`

Comment: thanks, that would make sense as this is running in test code on a fresh cluster.

Comment: `db.RunCommand<BsonDocument>("{ isMaster: 1 }")["localTime"].ToUniversalTime()`, perfect thanks.